# How to call more that one method inside of an `setOnItemClickListener(...`

Tags: java, android, gridview, onitemclicklistener

I have a `GridView` setup and I have implemented the `setOnItemClickListener` interface. Firstly I have made a little `Toast` just for feedback and then I moved on to calling my methods. The first method sort of works, I put it into a while loop that will call it until it  returns `true`. The second method, when inserted into the code, prevents the first method from  working at all, but I don't get any compiler errors.

Here is my `onCreate` containing the `setOnItemClickListener()` *with my second method I want to insert commented out*:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    final GameplayController gc = new GameplayController(this);

    // Create board model, add units to player's list.
    final UnitArray gameBoardModel = new UnitArray();

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            boolean next = false;
            while (next == false) {
                next = gc.choosePiece(position, gameBoardModel,
                        (ImageView) v);
            }
            /*next = false;
            while (next == false) {
                next = gc.chooseEmpty(position, gameBoardModel,
                        (ImageView) v);
            }*/
        }
    });
}
```

I say the first method "kinda" of works because it is a method that will check if the position in the `GridView` selected is an "allowable" selection and will update the `ImageView` at that selection and then `return true`, otherwise it will `return false` with the idea being that it will loop until the user makes a "valid" selection. Now, if a valid selection is made, it indeed does update the `ImageView` at the selection accordingly, but when an "invalid" selection is made it simply freezes.

So it "kinda" works, but when I insert my second method, it freezes even if a "valid" selection is made and it never makes it to the second method.

I think there is something I'm missing about the `onItemClickListener()`.

--------------------------EDIT-------------------ADDENDUM--------------

In case it helps to see the first method I'm calling,

```
public boolean choosePiece(int position, UnitArray ua, ImageView iv) {
    if (ua.checkPiece(pNum, position) == true) {
        if (ua.checkType(position, "rock")) {
            ImageView v = iv;
            v.setImageResource(R.drawable.rock1select);
            return true;
        }
        if (ua.checkType(position, "paper")) {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.paper1select);
            return true;
        }
        if (ua.checkType(position, "scissors")) {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.scissors1select);
            return true;
        }
    }
    /*
     * With just the IF statements above catching the correct selections, my
     * program crashes. I thought simply adding the RETURN FALSE; to catch
     * everything else would work since it should just keep looping from the
     * mAINaCTIVITY until it hits one of them and RETURNS TRUE;. So I will
     * add this ELSE so that it will just redraw what is already there,
     * maybe that will fix it? Like, maybe it really really wants to use the
     * freaking listener for something.
     * 
     * Nope, that didn't help at all.
     */
    else {
        System.out.println("Ohhhh, NO YOU DIDN'T!!!");
        if (ua.checkType(position, "rock")) {
            System.out.println("Bad rock!, BAD!");
            ImageView v = iv;
            v.setImageResource(R.drawable.rock2);
            return false;
        }
        if (ua.checkType(position, "paper")) {
            ImageView v = iv;
            v.setImageResource(R.drawable.paper2);
            return false;
        }
        if (ua.checkType(position, "scissors")) {
            ImageView v = iv;
            v.setImageResource(R.drawable.scissors2);
            return false;
        }
        if (ua.checkType(position, "empty")) {
            ImageView v = iv;
            v.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Maybe there is something here that I have to add to tell the `onItemClick..` to move on and stop sending touch events here??

Comment: It "freezes" because it runs into an infinite loop. In both of your while loops, you did not specify what to do if it finishes checking but still cannot find a valid position.

Comment: How would one go about specifying what to do when it finishes checking? I have it return true to move on to the next bit of code, or return false to go back in for another round. Is there something else I have to communicate to the `onItemClickListener` to let it know to move on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you know the number of elements that your GameplayController will look through:

```
boolean found = false;
int size = numberOfElements;
for(int i=0; i<size;i++) {
    if(gc.choosePiece(position, gameBoardModel,(ImageView) v)==true) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(found) {
// do what u expect
}
```

Comment: So maybe using a definite size loop may help, worth a shot! I'll try and report back.

Comment: So far so good, does not crash on invalid selections. Now, I'll try that second method.

Comment: Right on my man/woman/gender neutral! That's what I'm talking about.

Comment: I'll post completed section of code once finished for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

You say that when you add some code with a while loop to a method, the method appears to never successfully return.  Have you considered that the condition on which this second while loop executes never evaluates to false?  (In this case, when value "true" is assigned to variable "next"?)

If you are not sure, maybe you should add a System.out.println() inside each loop that outputs which loop is executing along with the value of "next", most likely it stays false forever or otherwise does not do what you think.

Comment: Most def, I did exactly that, and whenever I press an invalid selection it, sound weird but, it never unpresses the postion. So in my `println` it just keeps going and going. Like it never untouches it so I can make a new selection and keeps returning false.

Comment: It appears to "never" unpress because in order to unpress, first the call to onItemClickListener must return so more UI code can be run.  Your listener method gets stuck in an infinite loop and never returns.  The appearance of "unpressing" is supposed to happen after that.

Comment: Not just the appearance, it actually goes out and back in the method over and over again, the Sopln, just keeps returning ad infinitum. There has to be some method to like `liftPress` or `onUnpress` or something.

Comment: Don't know if I'm clear, I think not. It finishes the first method, but since it returns false it cycles and calls it again, but the original selection just stays pressed, thus never giving me an opportunity to press a valid selection to make it return true.

Answer (score 0):

Well my code was so terrible at the point of asking this question, but the immediate problem which cannot be unseen is that I was creating the `boolean next` INSIDE the onClick, so it was being reset everytime onClick occurred. Moving the creation of `boolean next` to before the onClick would have fixed the problem.

Sometimes I look at a little tiny problem for too long and can't see anything else but the problem even when the solution is crazy simple.